# How to focus on added row in grid when I have two grids?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two grids on WF. The left one is for employees, the right one is for theirs services. Each employee have different services.

[image]

On the contextMenuStrip I open other form which I need for inserting new employee and his service.

[image]

Now I add a new row in ORACLE database and in grids. But this row need to be in focus. How to do that, any idea? Workers are sorted by surname, and list of serveces are sorted by some identification. And visual studio focus some random row.

Comment: Does the row get added and sorted? Or is it just getting added to the end of the grid?

Comment: You could use the ID since it will be the biggest one

Comment: It is not sorted, just added... You think that I should sort it first and than just focus last row for example?

Comment: The `DataGridView` may be sorted, so selecting the last row doesn't make sense. The solution depends on how you add the record. Do you know the Id of inserted record after saving changes? Do you reload data of database into the grid after saving changes?

Comment: I know the id of inserted record after saving changes. On the right grid it is the id of the employee, on the left grid it is some id of the service and, also, id of the employee... And yes, I reload data after saving changes.

Comment: Sorry, on the left grid is id of empleyee(left grid is for employees), and on the right grid is id of the service and id of the employee(right grid is for services).